Turtle writing rotated text, but writes additional text
I found helpful posts on this site on how to get a Python turtle to write rotated text by using the create_text() method in the tkinter Canvas object. The turtle is writing exactly what I want but it's also writing an additional number beside each number I actually want, and I can't find where it's doing this, and how to prevent it. I'd be grateful if anyone can provide an explanation. I am using the inbuilt IDLE editor. My Python version is 3.10.7.
I have written code to draw a protractor. Here is the output:

Here is the code:
from turtle import *

c = getcanvas()
s = Screen()
s.setup(612, 328)

tracer(0)

t = Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.penup()
t.width(1.5)

def every_10(): # function called when ang%10 = 0
  t.penup()
  t.fd(36)
  t.pendown()
  t.fd(170) # length of long line from centre
  t.penup()
  t.fd(11) # move turtle out before writing first number
  # create canvas text object with rotated text
  angle_text = c.create_text(t.xcor(), -t.ycor(),
                             font=('Arial', 13, 'bold'),text=str(ang),
                             angle=(ang-90), anchor='center')
  t.write(angle_text) # write rotated first number
  t.fd(18) # move turtle out before writing second number
  angle_text = c.create_text(t.xcor(), -t.ycor(),
                             font=('Arial', 13, 'bold'),text=str(180-ang),
                             angle=(ang-90), anchor='center')
  t.write(angle_text) # write rotated second number
  t.fd(14) # move turtle out before drawing final line
  t.pendown()
  t.fd(50) # length of final line
  t.penup()

# move to starting position, draw small circle and horizontal and vertical lines
t.goto( 36, -138)
t.left(90)
t.pendown()
t.circle(36, 180)
t.goto(0, -138)
t.goto(0, -102)
t.goto(0, -138)
t.goto(36, -138)
t.penup()

# loop through angles from 0 to 180
for ang in range(181):
  t.penup()
  t.goto( 0, -138)
  t.setheading(ang)
  if ang % 10 == 0:
    every_10()
  elif ang % 5 == 0:
    t.fd(261)
    t.pendown()
    t.fd(38)
  else:
    t.fd(276)
    t.pendown()
    t.fd(23)
    
  
update()


c.create_text() is creating the rotated text, and then t.write() is creating the unrotated text (containing the ID number of the rotated text you just created).

Many thanks for this explanation. I had assumed you needed to use turtle write() to display the text but I've now discovered I can use c.pack() which produces the same text display without the extra numbers. I was also totally mystified as to what the extraneous numbers were - so thank you for explaining that as well!

UPDATE: I've now found you don't even need c.pack() - it seems it writes the text as soon as it executes the create_text() line.

@jasonharper Please post an answer instead of answering in the comments. OP can also post a self-answer so this thread is resolved for future visitors (comments are ephemeral).

Things like this are pretty easy to debug by just playing with those two lines. Trying to add and remove the lines one by one to reveal the behavior.

@jasonharper Done.

Answer provided by @jasonharper - see comments.

c.create_text() is creating the rotated text, and then t.write() is creating the unrotated text (containing the ID number of the rotated text you just created).

create_text() creates and draws the text item - there is no need to use any other code to display it.
The documentation for tkinter states that the function create_text(*args, **kw)

Draw text. Returns the item id.

So the unwanted numbers are the item id's of each of the rotated numbers.
